# What are the considerations when deleting the All Subscribers list and only adding contacts when emailing them?

Tags: marketing-cloud, bulk-delete, contact-deletion

I'm in the process of cleaning up our MC database to save on costs and improve efficiencies.

My question:

Considering our setup below, what would the downsides be if we were to delete our All Subscribers list on a regular basis and only import them when we need to email them? I'm thinking of the possibility of deleting records if they haven't done XYZ activity in the past 12 months and do not have an email address, is not removed, etc.

Some background:

- We use Salesforce and the Marketing Cloud Connector.
- We use a custom preference center that is synced to Salesforce and hence we treat the Email Opt Out field in Salesforce as the source of truth for unsubscribes.
- We only email contacts through Journey Builder and when doing so we always include a decision split to assess if the contact is opted in or out based on the value in Salesforce.

If I understand it correctly, this approach would: 
1) reduce the total billable contacts, 
2) lose email performance data in MC 
3) potentially lose bounce data and increase risk of poor deliverability,
 
4) contacts could reenter journeys that restrict contacts from entering only once, 
5) Unsure of this one, but we might lose email performance data pushed to the Individual Email Results object in Salesforce

I understand this is quite a dramatic approach to reducing billable contacts, but are there any other major drawbacks that I have not considered here?

Comment: You basically summed up the impacts. Quick answer of the assertion number 5: you won't actually lose email performance on IER on Sales/Service Cloud even if you delete the contact from SFMC. As for the assertion number 3, you can use an Auto-suppression as it is populated with Email Adresses and not SubscriberKeys.

Comment: Deleting from All Subscribers is not enough, when you want to reduce contact count. You will need to use Contact Deletion Framework instead. And deleting contacts after X months of inactivity, is a perfectly normal practice - not only from a cost, but also from a GDPR perspective.

Comment: @LukasLunow thank you, yes, we would probably look into deleting contacts from Contact Builder via API.